# Using XPath Contains function to transform configuration entry

Tags: xml, xpath, configuration

I have a set of configuration files that I have set to transform on build. In some cases, I need to replace only configuration entries that contain certain file names. What I do have problem with is getting a running query.

Below is the config transform entry in custom configuration section

```
 <filesettings file="application.remote.config" 
               filename="remote file config"    
               dir="C:\Remote\Download"                 
               backupdir="C:\Remote\Download\BackUp"
               xdt:Locator="XPath(//[contains(@file,'remote')])" />
```

Based on the above, I want to replace, during the transform target call, the filesettings entry that has the word remote in the filename. This currently gives the error **Expression must evaluate to a node-set.**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Predicates are only allowed after node steps. Your XPath expression

```
//[contains(@file,'remote')]
```

does not contain any. For example, use the wildcard matcher `*`

```
//*[contains(@file,'remote')]
```

or replace it by the node name which contains the `@file` attribute (if it's always the same).

Comment: Can you please recommend an excellent book on xpath? I would really love to learn this without the mush

Comment: I'm sorry, haven't ever looked into one -- had a rather good introduction in a university lecture. Basic XPath isn't very complicated, it gets more interesting when having to work around some limitations. I'm told the books on XSLT/XPath by Michael Kay (by the way, he's writing some very profound answers on stackoverflow on these topics) and XQuery by Priscilla Walmsley are good ones, but I'm not even sure what audience they're targeting.